# How to retrieve all objects from a Node in Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed the documentation, but no matter what, I cannot figure out how to return all the objects from a single node. For example, I want to return a list of all company objects from the `companies` node. Once I have that list, I want to parse them all into JSON objects. This is my first time with a NoSQL database so I'm sure that I'm missing something small.

Currently I have:

```
DatabaseReference companiesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("12265");

    companiesRef.child("companies").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.d("Count ", dataSnapshot.getChildren().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But it just returns `null` for the `value: DataSnapshot { key = companies, value = null }`.

Here's my database:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You create your reference like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("12265");
```

This means that Firebase looks at the root of the database and returns the child `12265` from under there. It does not automatically search the tree for a node with a matching name.

So you'll need to specify the entire path:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("android/users/12265");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add any parameters to your getReference() (let it go to the root of database) and then set the addListenerForSingleValueEvent. And you have not used getvalue() on you datasnapshot as well. Try this code:

```
DatabaseReference companiesRef =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

// this is the patch that I see from the image that you have attached.
companiesRef.child("telenotes").child("android").child("user").child("12265").child("companies").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Log.d("Count ", dataSnapshot.getChildren().getValue().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```